# How to split arabic documents into multiple sentences

Tags: nlp, arabic

Is there any method to split arabic documents into multiple sentences. Currently i'm using "."
for sentence splitting.

I'm looking for better sentence splitting models such as the ones available for english in opennlp.

Please let me know, if you know any packages which does this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Unicode Standard Annex #29 Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Sentence_Boundaries) specifies guidelines for determining default boundaries between user-perceived characters, words, and sentences.

ICU provides support for UAX #29 via [BreakIterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/BreakIterator.html).

UAX #29 provided text segmentation should be good enough for simple purposes, like triple-click selection of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done using pragmatic segmenter with MIT License. A rule based sentence splitter.

[Github Link](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter)

[Live Demo](https://www.tm-town.com/natural-language-processing)